# Understanding non zero space spaces of R^3

Tags: linear-algebra

Hello this explanation from my textbook explains that every nonzero subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$, other than $\mathbb{R}^3$ itself, is either $Span\{v_1,v_2\}$ for some linearly independent $v_1$ and $v_2$ or $Span\{v\}$ for $v \ne 0$. However I'm not exactly understanding what is the difference between these two examples. Would anyone mind helping me understand?
[image]

Comment: one is a two-dimensional subspace; the other is a one-dimensional subspace

Answer (score 1):

Basically, the book is saying all subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^3$ come in 4 kinds, two of which are obvious, namely $\mathbb{R}^3$ itself (which has dimension $3$) and the set $\{\vec{0}\}$ (which has dimension $0$). As is not hard to guess, the other kinds will have dimension $1$ and dimension $2$.

A vector space of dimension $1$ is a line through the origin, in other words it is the set $\{c\vec{x}| c \in \mathbb{R}\}$. Examples of this would be the $x$-axis ($\vec{x} = (1,0,0)$), the $y$-axis ($\vec{x} = (0,1,0)$) and the line $y=\pi x$ ($\vec{x} = (1,\pi,0)$).

A vector space of dimension $2$ is a plane through the origin, in other words it is the set $\{c\vec{x} + k\vec{y}|c,k \in \mathbb{R}\}$ assuming $\vec{x}$ and $\vec{y}$ are not collinear. For example, the choice of $\vec{x} = (1,0,0)$ and $\vec{y} = (0,1,0)$ leads to the $xy$-plane.